# how is closure working with let in js?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, closures

I am learning about the new features in **ES6**. I have a question about how **let** is really behaves, let's check the following example:

```
function aHero() {
  return 'Boy'
}

function aFoil() {
  return 'Rat'
}

function aDeed() {
  return 'Deed'
}

let sagas = [];
let hero = aHero();
let newSaga = function () {
  let foil = aFoil();
  sagas.push(function () {
    let deed = aDeed();
    console.log(hero + deed + foil)
  });
}

newSaga();
sagas[0]();
sagas[0]();
newSaga();
```

ES5: `var` scoped variable to entire function so when the code is running in browser, all variables been hoisted,  on the other side in **ES6** `let` scoped variable to its block so when run this code `saga[0]()` will print three words 'BoyDeedRat'

so I'm wondering how closure is really working with let ??

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here - this code will produce the same result whether you use `let` or `var` (or `const` for that matter) in those places.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes but it's normal to be working with var, I'm wondering why it's working with let?

Comment: @HazemHagrass Why _wouldn't_ it work with `let`?  All the variables are scoped to functions - there's no additional blocks going on here.

Comment: @JamesThorpe the question is that the call happened outside the scope, this foil function is just pushed to the array but called outside the scoop

Comment: @HazemHagrass Yes, that's [how closures work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1) - the function closes over the scope of `newSaga` that it was declared in. But it makes absolutely zero difference whether `foil` was declared with `let` or `var` in that scope.

Comment: You wouldn't notice any difference between var and let because you have no blocks. But if you do `const values = [1,2,3], funcsViaLet = [], funcsViaVar = [];

for(let value of values) { funcsViaLet.push(function(){return value})}
for(var value of values) { funcsViaVar.push(function(){return value})}`
You will notice that `funcsViaLet[0]()` gives 1, while `funcsViaVar[0]()` gives 3.

Comment: I believe it's clear, it was a little bit confusing. I believe that closures are totally different thing separated of using let/var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that in javaScript, the interpreter is understanding that you are creating a closure if function keyword is used another function and been returned. in most other common languages, after a function returns, all the local variables are no longer accessible because the context is destroyed, however in JavaScript, if a function is declared within another function, then all local variables can remain accessible after returning from the function you called. In simple words, the inner function will run in it's parent scope and can access all parents variables and function.
For detailed info check [this](http://hazemhagrass.com/index.php/2017/06/24/how-is-closure-working-with-let-in-js/) link.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, Safari and Firefox, `let` variables are local to the block, even within a loop.

Both

```js
(function(){
    let fns = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        fns.push(() => { console.log(i); });
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < fns.length; i++) {
        fns[i]();
    }
})();
```

and

```js
(function(){
    let fns = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let num = i; // closure will refer to separate values per iteration
        fns.push(() => { console.log(num); });
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < fns.length; i++) {
        fns[i]();
    }
})();
```

print

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

whereas using `var` instead of `let` in either case would print `4` five times.